# Google maps autocomplete works fine while AGM maps Fails to get load even after providing a apiKey

Tags: google-maps-api-3, agm

[![`I am able to get google place autocomplete response but fail to **load google maps** even after enabling all the apis from **google console apikey**

Thanks in advance
`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlVSc.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlVSc.png)

Comment: Error Image is attached above just near the text "Thanks in advance"

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that you have exceeded the number of free usage attempts on google maps service. you free daily quota will reset after midnight.

So if you would like to override that and keep using google maps you will need to add billing information for this project to continue to use Google Maps Platform.

See this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#StatusCodes

and this for more details:
https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits

Comment: Maps Embed Api calls are 0
Maps Javascript Api requests are 77

Answer (score 0):

Now, Google Maps requires you to enable a billing account, even if you will never exhaust your free quota. You can set up the billing account in your google cloud console.